# Genymotion network error when tried to register the installation

Tags: windows, macos, genymotion

I just installed **Genymotion**, when I started and tried to register via Genymotion app this error appeared:

> Network Error

[image: under login form]

Seems like Genymotion can't figure out a way to connect to Internet!

Comment: Did you figure out the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The Genymotion website has an FAQ section where they lay out an answer that worked for me:

https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#windows-ten-start-impossible

---

Why doesn't Genymotion run on Windows 10?

To date, VirtualBox is not yet fully compatible with Windows 10. As Genymotion relies on the use of VirtualBox in the background, some problems may arise. If you have any troubles running Genymotion on Windows 10, we first recommend that you put VirtualBox in a clean state.

To do so:

```
-Uninstall VirtualBox.
-Reboot your computer if prompted by the installer.
-Install the version of VirtualBox recommended for Windows 10
-Reboot your computer if prompted by the installer.
-Open VirtualBox and go to File > Preferences > Network.
-Remove all existing host-only networks by clicking Description 1.
```

Start Genymotion a first time.
In the event of a failure, start Genymotion a second time.
If Genymotion still doesn’t run, you can manually configure a host-only network:

```
-Open VirtualBox and go to File > Preferences > Network.
-Add a new host-only network by clicking Description 1.
-Edit its configuration by clicking Description 1.
-In the Adapter tab, set the following values:
-IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
-IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
-In the DHCP Server tab, set the following values:
-Check Enable Server.
-Server Address: 192.168.56.100
-Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
-Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.101
-Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254
```

---

The problem appears to be the VM default settings (I suspect they get cached after first run and a manual setup doesn't always take, hence the re-install procedure)

I never had to create a new Genymotion account, my original worked after I reinstalled the Oracle VM & applied the settings they give above. (You can download an update and it should uninstall the old version and fresh install the new)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

In Genymotion go to Settings-> Network and try to uncheck `Use HTTP Proxy`. This helped for me and hope helps others. I use Windows 7 Genymotion for personal use version 2.12.1.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. This helps me:

- Login to site.
- Press 'Send confirmation email'
- Click on the link in the confirmation email.

Comment: this was my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything but nothing worked. 
Try uninstalling Genymotion, create new account and then try to log in.
That is the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu BB) the problem was caused by Virtualbox not having a network setting for guests. Apparently the Genymotion tool is itself (apart from the generated devices) running on a virtual device, and if no network is available for guests in Virtualbox, it would fail to connect to the internet and hence this message at login.

To resolve, just add a Nat network in the Virtualbox tool at File/Preferences/Network.

(Would be nice if a search at the maker's site /Genymotion/ for the error message generated by their software actually returned a hit! And nothing wrong with having an error message bit more informative.)

Answer (score 0):

For those still having this issue, its a gateway issue.

**For Ubuntu**
type `netstat -r` to check network interfaces, now check the interface thats connected to the internet(wlan0 usually, you might see vboxnet0, ignore it).

1.copy the IP address and mask

2.open Virtual box(Latest Version->5.12)

3.click global tools,

4.click on Add(it will create vboxnet1)

5. now at IP column, paste the IP address, at mask column paste mask.
6. go to genymotion directory, open genymotion.ini
   change `host.only.???? = vboxnet0` to `host.only.??? = vboxnet1(or the name of the new interface you created)`.
   restart genymotion

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried few things to get it working without following the FAC as described in one of the answers above ( didn't remove VBox 5.2.16 and reinstall 5.2.6 .. didn't add a network adapter .. nothing of that)
Followed following steps:

- Remove HTTP proxy settings (or add one for testing and remove it)
- Go to Genymotion [reset login password](https://www.genymotion.com/account/password-reset/)
- Start VBox without starting any virtual devices

I guess starting VBox for first time does the job due to something in networking has bug in Genymotion.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1- Try to uninstall *Genymotion* and reinstall it.
2- If you are using an old version then install a new version.

The above steps worked for me:)

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and Reinstall Genymotion just works for me.

Answer (score -1):

In your, Genymotion goes to:

1. Settings -> Network
2. Check Use HTTP Proxy
3. Insert HTTP Proxy and Port
4. Click "OK"
5. Now try to login Genymotion.

I Hope to solve your problem.